# Binance API ETHUSDT wrong value

Tags: cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

btc_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCUSDT")

eth_price = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="ETHUSDT")

Basically I am trying to use the binance API to chart some prices and when I use "ETHUSDT" I get a static value of 146 and thats not even close to what it is. I am just wondering if I am missing something. Bitcoin one works fine